# .NET Core 5 Entity Framework how to return reversed pagination

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

My question is how to modify this

```
 var count = await source.CountAsync();
 var items = await source.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
```

to instead of returning classic incremental from start to end. Make this end to start so return last page and then go up (reverse pagination).

Whole class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace API.Helpers
{
    public class PagedList<T> : List<T>
    {
        public PagedList(IEnumerable<T> items, int count, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
        {
            CurrentPage = pageNumber;
            TotalPages = (int) Math.Ceiling(count / (double) pageSize);
            PageSize = pageSize;
            TotalCount = count;
            AddRange(items);
        }

        public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; set; }
        public int PageSize { get; set; }
        public int TotalCount { get; set; }

        public static async Task<PagedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
        {
            var count = await source.CountAsync();
            var items = await source.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
            return new PagedList<T>(items, count, pageNumber, pageSize);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT

```
public async Task<PagedList<MessageDto>> GetMessageThread (string currentUsername, string recipientUsername) 
{
    var messages = _context.Messages
                           .Where (m => m.Recipient.UserName == currentUsername 
                                        && m.RecipientDeleted == false 
                                        && m.Sender.UserName == recipientUsername || m.Recipient.UserName == recipientUsername 
                                        && m.Sender.UserName == currentUsername 
                                        && m.SenderDeleted == false)
                           .OrderBy (m => m.MessageSent)
                           .ProjectTo<MessageDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                           .AsQueryable ();
           
    return await PagedList<MessageDto>.CreateAsync (messages, new PaginationParams().PageNumber, new PaginationParams().PageSize);
}
```

Comment: `OrderByDescending`.

Comment: but if i have 50 pages it will order only one page i want already start at the last page like in facebook messenger where you have loaded last few messages and to load more you need to scroll up for more

Comment: To be clear my suggestion must be _before_ the `Skip`.

Comment: ok i need to figured it out how to overcome that source is type T and i cannot specify on what to order.... any suggestions?

Comment: Do the `OrderByDescending` in the _caller_ to `CreateAsync`.

Comment: edit my question with where i call that

Comment: `.OrderBy (m => m.MessageSent)` Change that to `OrderByDescending`.

Comment: it is not working cuz i am getting back first page but upside down i need to return last paged not first tihs only sort result for page not retruing last one

Comment: I strongly suspect you have not applied the change I suggested. Alas I don't have a different way of explaining it. I wish you the best in solving your problem.

Comment: server-side pagination code is going to need to receive the page # and page size to load. By default the pagination control is going to be tracking the "current" page client side, starting with the first page. The client-side control usually initializes with two methods, one to get the item count, and one to get a specific page of items. Client-side you need to override it to get the item count then reveal/calculate the # of pages so that the get current page requests the last page rather than the first.